# FOR XML PATH clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, concatenation, multiple-columns

I have a working script for my columns, so far so good, question is that- how I can hide those x and y columns? Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Result what I want to get is this- only Z column is showing. If I just make commented first line, it does not working and get error with xml path.

[image]

```
SELECT      
    C1S_PATIENTGROUP.PG_K AS [x], 
    C1S_PATIENTGROUP.NAME AS [y],
    SUBSTRING((SELECT ','+ [PatGroup].[PG_K] AS [text()]
               FROM D3_HOSPPATGROUPS [Hosp]
               INNER JOIN C1S_PATIENTGROUP [PatGroup] ON [Hosp].[PG_ID] = [PatGroup].[PG_ID]
               WHERE [Hosp].[HOSP_ID] = [card identificator]
               FOR XML PATH ('')), 2, 1000) AS [z] 
FROM         
    Z1_RPT_VIEW_15 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    D3_HOSPPATGROUPS ON Z1_RPT_VIEW_15.[card identificator] = D3_HOSPPATGROUPS.HOSP_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    C1S_PATIENTGROUP ON C1S_PATIENTGROUP.PG_ID = D3_HOSPPATGROUPS.PG_ID
```

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? In SQL Server 2017 and later you can use `STRINGG_AGG` instead

Comment: I don't get an error if removing `C1S_PATIENTGROUP.PG_K AS [x], C1S_PATIENTGROUP.NAME AS [y],` from the `SELECT`

Comment: FYI, if you want to remove the first character of a string, `STUFF` is far better suited.

Comment: Ohh, thanks to all of you for such great solutions. gonna figure something out.
I do not know about this solution to add stuff, gonna read about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Subquery can be used :

If I get it wrong please let me know so i delete it.

```
SELECT SUBQ.Z FROM 
(
select * from Integral_TranSELECT      
    C1S_PATIENTGROUP.PG_K AS [x], 
    C1S_PATIENTGROUP.NAME AS [y],
    SUBSTRING((SELECT ','+ [PatGroup].[PG_K] AS [text()]
               FROM D3_HOSPPATGROUPS [Hosp]
               INNER JOIN C1S_PATIENTGROUP [PatGroup] ON [Hosp].[PG_ID] = [PatGroup].[PG_ID]
               WHERE [Hosp].[HOSP_ID] = [card identificator]
               FOR XML PATH ('')), 2, 1000) AS [z] 
FROM         
    Z1_RPT_VIEW_15 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    D3_HOSPPATGROUPS ON Z1_RPT_VIEW_15.[card identificator] = D3_HOSPPATGROUPS.HOSP_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    C1S_PATIENTGROUP ON C1S_PATIENTGROUP.PG_ID = D3_HOSPPATGROUPS.PG_ID ) SUBQ
```

Comment: tried one, got some syntax errors about it. Do not know what is a best solution on this case, maybe it could be done with subq too. no clue.

Comment: try it, it should work